# Naming a String inside a loop

Tags: java, string, loops

Ok, so I wanted to make a small program that would ask the user for how many lines he'd like to type out, and how long they are.

So, at one point I ask him, how many lines he wants, and it saves them as `int` called `H`.
After that, I'd ask him for a string, `H` times. And I'd save them all.
I could use a for loop to ask him `H` times, but how do I save the strings differently?

This is what I thought of doing

```
for (int z=0; z <= H; z++) {
    System.out.println("Introduza os " +V+ "valores da linha " +z+ ".") ;
    String StringContar = System input.nextLine();
    while (StringContar.length() <= V+1){
        System.out.println("Introduza os " +V+ "valores da linha " +z+ ".");
        String String(+z+) = System input.nextLine();
    }
```

`V` would the length, but how do I prevent the program from only saving the last string?

Comment: Hint - you're asking for a *collection* of lines. So you should be storing them in a *collection* (e.g. a list or an array)

Comment: Why name the variable `H` instead of, say, `linhas`?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    list.add(in.next());
    }
```

Comment: Look around this sample and implement your own way :)